# Issue about passing an NSARRAY values from one class to another over a TABBAR controller and a Navigation Controller

Tags: ios

**First view Controller .m**

```
array=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c", nil];
```

**SecondTable View controller .m**

```
ViewController *objView=[[ViewController alloc]init];
NSLog(@"Array is%@",objView.array);
```

In between first view Controller and secondTable View controller there
is an navigation Controller and a Tab bar controller

Comment: How your are pasing?
where you are setting arry in your secondviewcontroller?

Comment: array is setting on .h with property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want the way of you are approaching , then 
**Initialize the array in `init` method of the FIrstViewController.m**

```
-(id)init{
    array=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"aa",@"bb",@"cc", nil];
    return self;
}
```

I hope that, you are about to initialise the `NSArray` in the `ViewDidLoad` method.Then the array could be nil due to you are just `init` the Controller.

**Note** : Not recommended in this way.

Answer (score 2):

**you can do it by defining an array property in second viewcontrollers .h file like:**

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController {
NSMutableArray *array;
}
@property(nonatomic, assign)NSArray *array;
```

**in .m file synthesize it like**

```
@synthesize array;
```

**Now in FirstViewconrtoller just assign it**

```
 SecondViewController *controller = [[SecondViewController alloc]....]
 controller.array = yarArray.//the array you want to pass
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: i want the nsarray from first view controller to my table view